# How to make home made corn flakes?

Tags: baking, dough, corn

I looked at the history of Corn Flakes on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_flakes) but it doesn't really tell me how I could go from raw ingredients to the final product. Should I use corn flour ? What should I do to make the final product in shape of flakes ? Should I cook it in a oven or in a pan ?

Comment: If you do try making corn flakes, you should come back and post an answer of how you did it and how it turned out. Would be interested to know!

Comment: @standgale Sure ! I think I'll try the recipe mentioned in Martin Jevon's answer very soon. When it's done I'll give a feedback and accept one of the answers.

Comment: @standgale I tested the recipe in Martin Jevon's answer. I made the mistake of buying wheaten cornflour instead of corn starch but the result turned out well. I didn't evaluate the global cost (ingredients, electricity, etc) to see how it compares to Corn Flakes from the supermarket and I doubt it saves any money, but it was fun to make !

Comment: Great, I might try it some time! Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use corn meal, for the constituency and texture.

Here is a recipe link that I think will answer all of your questions including how to cook.

http://www.alwaysorderdessert.com/2014/03/homemade-corn-flakes-cereal.html

Back in 2009 the bbc in the uk aired a tv programme called jimmys food factory, which explored ways of making commercially produced food stuffs in a home environment.   The very first episode covered the making of corn flakes.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00nk0j5

Answer (score 2):

Reference 1 in your Wikipedia link, [the patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US558393), describes the process as it was in 1895.
Flakes of "corn, and other grains" appear to have been a bit of an afterthought.
The basic process is: hot soak, cook, roll, steam cook, roast dry. Looks pretty tedious to do in a home kitchen, but possible with some effort.

Comment: I didn't even think of looking at the patent. Thanks for digging deeper than me ! Like you say it doesn't seem to be a very easy process to apply at home.

Comment: @rold2007 Old patents are a great way of figuring out how something is done. Newer cornflake production methods are likely even less home friendly than the old one.